# Embedded DT::datatable() is scrollable when viewed via "Infinite Moon Reader" but not in browser

Tags: r, datatables, rstudio, dt, xaringan

When I knit and view the example below using Infinite Moon Reader in RStudio, I get a scrollable datatable, but when I view the same file in a browser (safari, chrome, firefox) the datatable is not scrollable. The same (not scrollable) do I get when I knit the example "manually" via CTRL-CMD-K (internal and external viewer the same).

Am I missing something, or is this a bug? Do I have to use the RStudio GUI to give that presentation?

Somehow I have the feeling, that the browser does not ind the java library from [datatable](https://datatables.net) and the server which is used by Infinite Moon Reader does?

Also, the tables are presented differently:

Infinite Moon Reader:

[image]

In the browser:

[image]

The example is as followed:

````
---
title: "Only Scrolls when using Infinite moon reader"
subtitle: "When opening html or connecting to 127.0.0.1 it does not scroll<br/><html><div style='float:left'></div><hr color='#EB811B' size=1px width=796px></html>"
author: "Rainer M Krug"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      beforeInit:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      navigation:
        scroll: false
        click: false
        touch: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
library(magrittr)
library(DT)
library(xaringan)
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
data.frame(
  a = 1:100, b = 1:100, c = 1:100, f = 1:100
) %>%
  datatable(
    options = list(
      pageLength = 200,
      dom = "ti",
      ordering = FALSE
    ),
    height = 600
  )
```

---

```{r, echo = FALSE}
sessionInfo()
```
````

Comment: I tried out the example by deleting the options in `datatable()`, it's paginated but not scrollable.

Comment: Yup - But I would prefer the scrollable one.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution that works:

```
data.frame(
  a = 1:100, b = 1:100, c = 1:100, f = 1:100
) %>%
  datatable(
    options = list(
      scrollY = 600,
      pageLength = 200,
      dom = "ti",
      ordering = FALSE
    )
  )
```

This is how the slide will appear when you open it in any browser:

[image]